# Is it possible turn off the compass in Call of Duty: World at War?

Tags: call-of-duty-world-at-war

I'm surprised that you cannot remove the compass on this game. In 1941 no one had a device that told them where the enemies are and where targets are. I've had to stick some paper on my TV to cover up the radar for the added realism.

In similar games - such as Medal of Honor - it is possible to disable HUD elements. Can I do the same in Call of Duty: World at War too?

Comment: Hello Tim. What exactly is your question? This seems more like a rant than anything else

Comment: If realism is your goal, it seems that it's possible to turn off the HUD by following the steps listed on this [wiki page](https://nohud.fandom.com/wiki/Call_of_Duty:_World_at_War_No_Hud).

Comment: You need edit to your post to include the question "is it possible to hid the minimap in CoD:WaW?" Right now this post is 100% opinionated and not suitable for StackExchange. Many players (myself included) appreciate the utility of the minimap (or compass - as you call it) in the game.

Comment: The question is am I missing something and you can turn off the compass in this game? And why would anyone think to create or play such a game with this massive cheat enabled - that question is to the developers and players.

Comment: @PausePause It works for me (chrome and firefox, Windows).

Comment: Tim, you should consider moving this to Gaming StackExchange Chat. Regardless, [designing for accessibility](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PJoax1Z1x4Y&vl=en) is a major component of game design. Players with impairments could be limited from enjoying games if they were unable to ,say, read subtitles or use the minimap. @RoikanEskor Link works now. IDK what happened.

Comment: Thanks for the link but I think thats for pc only whereas im using a ps3.

Comment: I think I have no choice but to stick some paper in the bottom left corner of the screen. Seems extremely odd that they didnt give the option to turn this mini radar map off and the option to turn off the crosshairs

Comment: To those who vote for this question to be closed as off-topic, because it is about game design, or development: This question is asking if a feature exists in the game, not why it does, or doesn't exists. Some of the comments are about game design, but the question itself is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered in the comments @Tim is playing on PS3. Unfortunately, there are no settings in-game to remove the HUD. Certain multiplayer game modes such as the Hardcore Playlist will disable the HUD but these features are not available in the campaign. I'm sorry, but without modding the console (and risking game bans from Treyarch) the HUD will have to remain.

As an aside, @Tim has expressed that they enjoy hardcore/immersive shooter games. I'd recommend the Operation Flashpoint series. It's a modern military shooter for the PS3 with realistic squad tactics and damage models. It might interest you.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help and suggestions. I have a large smart tv so sticking some paper over the hud thing wont be too much inconvenience! Thanks!

Comment: If you feel like this answered the question don't forget to mark the answer as accepted

Comment: Is clicking the green tick button the way to accept the answer?

Comment: Yeah. The green checkmark accepts answers to questions you've posted. Feel free to post more questions to the site if you have any.